# Android Thai Localization

Tags: android, localization, thai

I have implemented language localization to an Android application.

My questions are:

1. I can't seem to test if the localization works, as Android doesn't seem to support Thai natively. Is this the case?
2. If a Thai font pack was installed on a phone using my App, would the    "Locale.getDefault()...... code detect that font pack the same as any other natively supported language and act appropriately.

No similar questions that I can see answer my question.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried this on my stock HTC Sensation and Thai language works and has the fonts to display it properly. Try using a program called "morelocale2" (I have no affiliation with this app) in the Android Market. It will allow you to set your phone's language to any of the Android supported languages. It makes testing localization much easier.